Split content and paginate in Astro.js
I have a file that is used as a dynamic route
[...slug].astro
---
export const prerender = true;
import { type CollectionEntry, getCollection } from 'astro:content';
import BlogPost from '../layouts/StandardPages.astro';

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const posts = await getCollection('pages');
    return posts.map((post) => ({
        params: { slug: post.slug },
        props: post,
    }));
}
type Props = CollectionEntry<'pages'>;

const post = Astro.props;
const { Content } = await post.render();
---

<BlogPost {...post.data}>
    <Content />
</BlogPost>


and i need to split divide the content further, and paginate it, but i don´t get the methodology. What code can be used?
Thx

Could you clarify what you mean by "split content" / "divide the content further" and how that's separate from pagination? Could you give an example of what your desired end state is for content splitting?

Well, if the content in a md file is too long, i want to have page 2 for example..

the "for example" in your comment does a lot of work here. please clarify your question to what exactly you want, what you tried and how it failed.
